# Changing braces in a string with data from a json

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, google-apps-script

I have a template string that I want to change words with {{}} around them to data of a similar name from a json file. I am using google apps script for this.

Ex.
Hello my name is {{First Name}} {{Last Name}}. --> Hello my name is Sherlock Holmes.

Json file would be:

```
[ { 'First Name': 'Sherlock',
'Last Name': 'Holmes'  }  ]
```

I have tried using this code where template is the string and data is the json:

```
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
   let template_string = template;

   // Token replacement
   template_string = template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
     return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "");
   });
   return  JSON.parse(template_string);
  }

  function escapeData_(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
      .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
      .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
      .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
      .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
      .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
      .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
  };
```

But it just removes the braces instead of replacing them.
ex.
Hello my name is .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `data` variable is a dictionary within an array, referencing `data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")]` returns `undefined`. This can be remedied by instead inputting the following for your `data` variable.

```json
{ 'First Name': 'Sherlock',
'Last Name': 'Holmes' }
```

Additionally, parsing `template_string` is unnecessary.

```js
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
   let template_string = template;

   // Token replacement
   template_string = template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
     return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "");
   });
   return template_string;
  }

  function escapeData_(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
      .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
      .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
      .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
      .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
      .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
      .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did what you said (the data var now is a dictionary) and I'm now getting this error 
"TypeError: str.replace is not a function" at .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\') (the first instance of .replace in escapeData_()).

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it by using JSON.stringify();